# Display Template lookup column additional fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, lookup-column, display-template, managed-property

I have a search based solution where I work alot with Display Templates to render out results in a fancy way. It all works fine and dandy with Managed Properties mapped up etc.

However, I've come across an issue where I have a lookup column on my target list. The lookup-column is configured to also include additional fields. See embedded image.

I am able to get the lookup column itself in the display template by mapping a Managed Property to it, I am however not able to get the additional fields.

I found some crawled properties in the following format:

```
SharePoint:Postnummer

SharePoint:Poststed
```

and they both have an internal fieldname in the format 
`ows_CustomerLeverandor:Postnummer`, etc., which tells me, since it's the same format as displayed on the list with the lookup-column, that this might be the very same column that is displayed when I'm in the list.

However when mapping this crawled property, including the Managed Property in the `<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>`-section, it does not extract any values from them.

Anyone encountered this particular problem before? Is there another way to do it or might it be my crawler that isn't working properly?

Kind regards,
Ole

Attachment:

[image: Lookup column additional fields.]